# How can I open package navigator view in Software AG designer?

Tags: package, webmethods

I hit a debug button to see how my service work and a popup appear.

I did not pay much attention and just hit 'switch' on the popup
and now I lost my package navigator view...

I cannot find the way to reopen it! please help!
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Window > Show View > others > search 'package'